# Android Architecture Components with Firebase specifically Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I was going through this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html) by [Doug Stevenson](https://twitter.com/CodingDoug) (Firebase Developer Advocate)
The blog talks about how to use the **firebase realtime database** with android architecture components.

Theres a class `FirebaseQueryLiveData` that forms a reusable class to manage all Firebase queries as well as implementing LiveData. This though applies perfectly to the Firebase RealTime database, **I can't seem to change or alter it to support the cloud firestore database.**

Here is the code

```
public class FirebaseQueryLiveData extends LiveData<DataSnapshot> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "FirebaseQueryLiveData";

    private final Query query;
    private final MyValueEventListener listener = new MyValueEventListener();

    public FirebaseQueryLiveData(Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public FirebaseQueryLiveData(DatabaseReference ref) {
        this.query = ref;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActive");
        query.addValueEventListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onInactive");
        query.removeEventListener(listener);
    }

    private class MyValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            setValue(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't listen to query " + query, databaseError.toException());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the difficulties or errors are.  What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Hey Bob. Firestore does not have similar methods like Firebase Realtime i.e ValueEventListener, addValueEventListener. It has other implementations of the same, which am finding difficult to use in this above logic

Comment: It runs well when i work on the Firebase RealTime database but i cant use the same with Firestore.

Comment: Firestore has a Query with snapshot listeners.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query

Comment: Can this class FirebaseQueryLiveData run as it is with Firestore..

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried to write it with document snapshots instead. Runs well so far

Comment: Could you post the appropriate ViewModel class? because that blog shows for the real-time database ViewModel, not for firestore.

Comment: how to write to DB (Firestore) using android architecture components (Jetpack)? Can anyone point me to some code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for ask it. You help me! But, you know how to update query? Something like a new WHERE clause. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: @AbnerEscócio Just construct a query, add `Where` then pass into the `FirebaseQueryLiveData` class

Answer (score 12):

This is the Query version of @JobM post. Thank you @JobM!  I would recommend renaming @JobM's version to FirebaseDocumentLiveData for clarity.

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class FirebaseQueryLiveData extends LiveData<QuerySnapshot> {
    public static final String TAG = "FbaseQueryLiveData";

    private Query query;
    private final MyValueEventListener listener = new MyValueEventListener();
    private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;

    private boolean listenerRemovePending = false;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    public FirebaseQueryLiveData(Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    private final Runnable removeListener = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listenerRegistration.remove();
            listenerRemovePending = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();

        Log.d(TAG, "onActive");
        if (listenerRemovePending) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(removeListener);
        }
        else {
            listenerRegistration = query.addSnapshotListener(listener);
        }
        listenerRemovePending = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();

        Log.d(TAG, "onInactive: ");
        // Listener removal is schedule on a two second delay
        handler.postDelayed(removeListener, 2000);
        listenerRemovePending = true;
    }

    private class MyValueEventListener implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null){
                Log.e(TAG, "Can't listen to query snapshots: " + querySnapshot + ":::" + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            setValue(querySnapshot);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works for firebase queries, thanks @Brian Begun

Comment: Updated to include handler and delay detaching listener to prevent unnecessary calls to Firestore (device orientation changes)

Comment: Works fine! We need Kotlin version.

Comment: please post the ViewModel class as well

Comment: please post the ViewModel (with transformations.map) class as well

Answer (score 8):

For the lovers of Kotlin :)

```
import android.os.Handler
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import com.google.firebase.firestore.*
import timber.log.Timber

class FirebaseQueryLiveData(private val query: Query) : LiveData<QuerySnapshot>() {
    private val listener = MyValueEventListener()
    private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration? = null

    private var listenerRemovePending = false
    private val handler = Handler()

    private val removeListener = Runnable {
        listenerRegistration!!.remove()
        listenerRemovePending = false
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()

        Timber.d( "onActive")
        if (listenerRemovePending) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(removeListener)
        } else {
            listenerRegistration = query.addSnapshotListener(listener)
        }
        listenerRemovePending = false
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()

        Timber.d("onInactive: ")
        // Listener removal is schedule on a two second delay
        handler.postDelayed(removeListener, 2000)
        listenerRemovePending = true
    }

    private inner class MyValueEventListener : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
        override fun onEvent(@Nullable querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, @Nullable e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
            if (e != null) {
                Timber.e(e, "Can't listen to query snapshots: %s", querySnapshot)
                return
            }
            value = querySnapshot
        }
    }
}
```