# LiveData not refreshing RecyclerView after Firestore update

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Android app which uses firestore as its database. I have followed this  series of blog posts to set up my firestore database in my app : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html and then followed this stackoverflow entry to change my code to work for firestore: [Android Architecture Components with Firebase specifically Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798814/android-architecture-components-with-firebase-specifically-firestore).

After this I was successful to display the result of my query in a recycler view, however when I added the swap to update (I do soft delete by setting a isActive flag to false) action in my app, LiveData was inconsistent in refreshing the RecyclerView. Here is my code snippets:

MainActivity.java

```
  TaskViewModel viewModel = 
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TaskViewModel.class);

    LiveData<LinkedList<TaskProperties>> liveData = viewModel.getTaskPropertiesLiveData();

    final MainActivity mainActivityReference =  this;

    liveData.observe(this, new Observer<LinkedList<TaskProperties>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable LinkedList<TaskProperties> taskProperties) {
            if (taskProperties != null) {

                // Get a handle to the RecyclerView.
                mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
                // Create an adapter and supply the data to be displayed.
                mAdapter = new TaskListAdapter(mainActivityReference, taskProperties);
                // Connect the adapter with the RecyclerView.
                ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(mAdapter);

                ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);

                touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                // Give the RecyclerView a default layout manager.
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mainActivityReference));
            }
        }
    });
```

View Model:

```
public class TaskViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LinkedList<TaskProperties> taskProperties;
    private static final Query PROJECT_REF = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("project").whereEqualTo("active", true);

    private final FirebaseQueryLiveData liveData = new FirebaseQueryLiveData(PROJECT_REF);

       public TaskViewModel() {
      taskPropertiesLiveData.addSource(liveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                if (querySnapshot != null) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            taskProperties =  new LinkedList<TaskProperties>();
                            for (DocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot.getDocuments()) {
                                taskProperties.addLast(document.toObject(TaskProperties.class));

                            }

                            taskPropertiesLiveData.postValue(taskProperties);
                        }
                    }).start();
                } else {
                    taskPropertiesLiveData.setValue(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    public LiveData<LinkedList<TaskProperties>> getTaskPropertiesLiveData() {
        return taskPropertiesLiveData;
    }
}
```

Code in the callback class to remove :

```
 public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

Constructor in Adapter:-

```
  public TaskListAdapter(Context context,LinkedList<TaskProperties> taskList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.taskList = taskList;
    }
```

Code in Adapter to remove:-

```
  public void onItemDismiss(int position) {

        TaskDao taskDao = new TaskDao();
        taskDao.softDeleteTaskInDB(taskList.get(position));
    }
```

Code in DAO class to update( soft delete) :-

```
public void softDeleteTaskInDB(TaskProperties taskProperties){

    taskProperties.setActive(false);
    database.collection("project")
            .document(taskProperties.getTask())
            .set(taskProperties).
            addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                }
            });

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG,taskProperties.getTask());

}
```

I have observed that LiveData was able to refresh the view when I was deleting one component from the end of the list, however when I deleted from the middle of the list the view sometimes does not refresh properly. From the logs I found that the position that is being passed into the adapter class is working fine, however the tasklist array does not have the most updated value.

For example if the task list contains :-

- Cat
- Dog
- Mouse
- Rabbit
- Tiger

and if delete Mouse and then Rabbit in quick succession, the onItemDismiss in adapter class receives position 3 in both cases, but the taskList variable in the Adapter class still contains Mouse at position 3. This means the LiveData might not have refreshed the RecyclerView.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
Sangho

Comment: Where do you call `onSwiped`?

Comment: I do not explicitly call onSwiped, it is defined in the callback class. I call the onItemDismiss function from the ViewAdapter class.

Comment: I think I have solved the issue, I had followed this blog: [link] https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf to write the code for the swipe and move actions in the recycler view. While following the code I missed to add notifyItemRemoved(position) in the onItemDismiss function of the Adapter.